# Convert String To Java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, string, date, jdbc

After looking through many of the threads in stackoverflow and cant seem to find the correct method im looking for. If anyone could shine a bit of light it would be great.

So I populated a JCombo Box with SQL Dates but in doing so I formatted them to using SimpleDateFormat which converted them into a string with the format dd/MM/yyyy.

When the program is running he can select a certain date to query the database and so here the problem

Ive managed to make a String with a format of yyyy/MM/dd using string.split saving it into an array and ordering them in another string

Is There A Way To Convert This String (2014/04/13) into an SQL Date so I can query my database OR am I going about it incorrect

Thank You,

Answer (score 4):

> Is There A Way To Convert This String (2014/04/13) into an SQL Date?

Sample code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    try {
        java.util.Date utilDate = format.parse("2014/04/13");
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(sqlDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output:

```
2014-04-13
```

> use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a string into `java.util.Date`.
>
> use [java.sql.Date(miliseconds)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor.

Comment: Thanks Braj works a treat I just slotted my formatted String in instead of "2014/04/13". It was really bugging me for the last 2 hours. Did not think of bring in java.util.date even though java.sql.date is a subclass. Cheers again

Comment: yes you can do it in same manner `java.util.Date newUtilDate=new  java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());`

Comment: I logic behind is the milliseconds that is used in constructor of both the classes.

Comment: `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Comment: Is there any date in your database that is older than January 1, 1970?

Comment: No there isnt i am aware off the constraints with using the milliseconds, all dates are only 10 years old at the max, thanks again for all the information..

Comment: but still there is no issue in such case. you will get time in negative but it will work fine.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use [java.util.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

An example here:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    java.lang.Date langDate = sdf.parse("2014/04/13");
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(langDate.getTime());
```

Comment: **Sorry you have used `mm` in place of `MM`. That is wrong. I have already posted it. Please look into again.**

Comment: FYI, the terribly-designed `java.sql.Date` class has been supplanted by `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "23/01/2018" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
    ) 
) ;
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Define a formatting pattern to match your input strings.

```
String input = "23/01/2018" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
String output = localDate.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Use smart objects rather than dumb text for database interactions.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).